# Case-when w.r.to Count in sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am getting error in the below sql query.

if count is >1  i need to execute when statement, if not else statement.

```
 SELECT CASE
     WHEN (COUNT(VALUE) FROM TABLE1 WHERE ID=111)>1 )
    THEN 
    SELECT VALUE FROM TABLE2 WHERE ID=111 
    ELSE
    SELECT 2
```

Please help

Comment: Could you edit your question and add some sample data and expected results? Is that meant to be the entire query?

Comment: What is w.r.to ? I've seen this a few times, and google searches lead here... where it also isn't explained.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if (select count(*) from table1 where id = 111 group by id) > 1
select value from table2 where id = 111
else
select 2
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/GUIC32565)

The same thing, written using `case when...`

```
select 
case 
when (select count(*) from table1 where id = 111 group by id) > 1 then value
else 2 
end
from table2
where id = 111
```

Comment: Original statement uses two different tables.

Comment: Thanks. It worked.But could you please help me to write this using case-when?

Answer (score 0):

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM TABLE1 WHERE ID='111' HAVING COUNT(VALUE)>1)
     BEGIN
     SELECT VALUE FROM TABLE2 WHERE ID=111 
     END
     ELSE
     BEGIN
     SELECT 2
     END
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this sample code

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE
  (
     id    INT,
     value INT
  )

INSERT @Table1
VALUES(1,
       10)

INSERT @Table1
VALUES(2,
       20)

DECLARE @TABLE2 TABLE
  (
     id INT,
     c2 INT
  )

INSERT @TABLE2
VALUES(1,
       11 )

INSERT @TABLE2
VALUES(2,
       22 )

SELECT CASE
         WHEN (SELECT count(value)
               FROM   @Table1) > 0 THEN (SELECT T2.c2
                                         FROM   @TABLE2 T2
                                         WHERE  T1.id = T2.id)
         ELSE (SELECT T2.id
               FROM   @TABLE2 T2
               WHERE  T1.id = T2.id)
       END
FROM   @Table1 t1
```